# VHDL array index out of bound

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, vivado

I'm having problem with the synthesis of my VHDL program (a Finite State Machine); the error is:

> [Synth 8-97] array index 'number' out of bound

but I am pretty sure that my index never reaches that 'number' (precisely 255). Furthermore the behavioral simulation works.

Here is some of my code (where the error occurs):

```
K := 0;
 while (K < var_col) loop --var_col is set to 24
   if (array_col(K) = '1') then  --the error is here
      tot_col := tot_col + 1 + num_zero;
      num_zero := 0;
   else
      tot_rows := tot_rows;
      if (tot_col > 0) then
         num_zero := num_zero + 1;
      else
         num_zero := 0;
      end if;
   end if;
   K := K + 1;
 end loop
```

I declared the array this way

```
architecture Behavioral of A is
   subtype my_array is std_logic;
   type my_array0 is array (0 to 254) of my_array;
--other signals declaration

begin
state_comb: process(sensitivity list)
    variable array_col : my_array0 := (others => '0');
```

How can I solve my problem?

I use Vivado 2017.3

Comment: How is `var_col` assigned?

Comment: Synthesising while loops is ... brave. If you can transform it into a for loop with constant bounds, more synth tools are likely to support that properly. For more help, make this example an [MCVE] which will at least reveal whether or not the above is part of a synchronous process (probably OK) or otherwise (probably not OK).

Comment: Why aren't you using `for K in 0 to var_col loop`?

Comment: Preferably don't use variables. You should use a signal instead.

Comment: Synthesis of while loops is not supported, because it's very hard to solve the synthesis problem. It's hard to foresee what indices are generated by such a loop.

Comment: @JHBonarius wild guess : because var_col is not locally static, producing other errors. As in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369917/getting-error-from-for-loops-in-vhdl/369935#369935

Comment: Thanks all for the reply; var_col is a variable and I cannot modify its type because I need it to be a variable; how can I set a valid range for the loop?

Comment: @BrianDrummond it's a synchronous process.

Comment: Maybe you should add the line `assert var_col<255 report "var_col is definitely larger then 254" severity failure;` before your while loop.

Comment: @JHBonarius That won't help in synthesis, though it should catch the error if it occurred in simulation. Which reminds me : Xilinx ISE Simulator (pre-Vivado) ran with bounds checks/overflow checks OFF by default; you had to go to "advanced options" to turn it on. Crazy but true. Worth checking if they ever got round to fixing that in Vivado?

Comment: By the way, is var_col a constrained integer?

Comment: Your shown snippet can use a for iteration scheme for the loop. The index range of array_col and K, var_col constraints should match. `for K in var_col'range loop`, eliminating the present variable K and it's assignments. The sequence of retained statements enclosed in an if statement evaluating K < var_col. Don't assign var_col in the sequence of statements. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using variables is generally not recommended.  If possible use for signals.

Having said that, there are situations in which variables make sense.  There are, for example, functions that can easily be computed in a number of iterations, but you cannot compute them in a single line.  One could also use generate statements in that case, but that becomes less readable.  However, I would encapsulate such code into functions and use signals anywhere else.

Anyway, after completing your function, I obtained the same error message as you did.  The problem is that the synthesis tool apparently is not able to figure out that the range of `var_col` is limited.  The solution is easy: Tell the synthesis tool what the range is by adding, for example, `range 0 to 24` to the variable declaration.  Following is my code:

```
library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity A is
   port
   (
     ival  : in  std_logic_vector(254 downto 0);
     iters : in  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
     oval  : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
   );
end A;

architecture Behavioral of A is
   subtype my_array is std_logic;
   type my_array0 is array (0 to 254) of my_array;

begin
  state_comb: process(ival)
    variable array_col: my_array0 := (others => '0');
    variable K:         integer;
    variable var_col:   integer range 0 to 24;
    variable tot_col:   integer;
    variable num_zero:  integer;
    variable tot_rows:  integer;
  begin
    for i in 0 to 254
    loop
      array_col(i) := ival(i);
    end loop;

    K := 0;
    var_col := to_integer(unsigned(iters));
    while (K < var_col) loop --var_col is set to 24
     if (array_col(K) = '1') then  --the error is here
        tot_col := tot_col + 1 + num_zero;
        num_zero := 0;
     else
        tot_rows := tot_rows;
        if (tot_col > 0) then
           num_zero := num_zero + 1;
        else
           num_zero := 0;
        end if;
     end if;
     K := K + 1;
   end loop;

   oval <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(tot_col, 10));
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

By the way, assigning `tot_rows` to `tot_rows` makes no sense.

Moreover, you claim that your process is synchronous, but you call it `state_comb`.  Unless `comb` is not referring to combinational, it makes no sense.